# Django update rows base on order in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a simple django model

```py
class Item(Model):
  name = CharField()
  rank = PositiveIntegerField()
  created_at = DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to update the object rank based on their order when sorted by a field (name or created_at)
e.g. when ordering by name

```py
[("Pen", 0, "2021-05-04"), ("Ball", 0, "2021-05-04")] => [("Pen", 1, "2021-05-04"), (Ball, 0, "2021-05-04")]
```

I already know I can do this using bulk_update but it means I have to fetch the objects in memory

```py
items = Items.objects.order_by("name")
for i, item in enumerate(items):
  item.rank = i
Item.objects.bulk_update(items, ["rank"])
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it with 1 query directly in the database, without having to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    rank smallint
);

insert into items(id, name, rank) values (1, 'A', 0);
insert into items(id, name, rank) values (2, 'B', 0);
insert into items(id, name, rank) values (3, 'C', 0);
```

```sql
select * from items;
```

| id | name | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 3 | C | 0 |

```sql
UPDATE items
SET rank=calculated.calc_rank
FROM
  (SELECT id AS calc_id,
          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                              ORDER BY name ASC)) AS calc_rank
   FROM items) AS calculated
WHERE items.id = calculated.calc_id;
```

```sql
select * from items;
```

| id | name | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 3 | C | 3 |

And [perform raw SQL for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/):

```py
sql = '''
UPDATE items
SET rank=calculated.calc_rank
FROM
  (SELECT id AS calc_id,
          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                              ORDER BY name ASC)) AS calc_rank
   FROM items) AS calculated
WHERE items.id = calculated.calc_id
'''

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  cursor.execute(sql)
```